# Angularjs resource and http 302 and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs, jetty

When using AngularJS and the phone demo application I try this:

```
var phonecatServices = angular.module('phonecatServices', ['ngResource']);

phonecatServices.factory('Phone', function($http) {
var myService = {
   query: function() {
// $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
    var promise = $http.get('http://192.122.122.1:4040/data/json/').then(function (response) {
    // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
    console.log(response.data);
    // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
    return response.data;
    });
// Return the promise to the controller
return promise;
}
};
return myService;
});
```

And then I try this alternative approach as per the original example:

```
phonecatServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
function($resource){
 ar x= $resource('http://192.122.122.1:4040/data/json/', {}, {
 query: {method:'GET', isArray:false}
 });
 console.log(x)
 return x;
 }]);
```

Then I get this in Chrome and Firefox:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

I have these defined in my Jetty servlet:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
```

When I do a curl:

```
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: 192.122.122.1:4040
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/json;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,     Accept
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Content-Length: 38
* Server Jetty(8.1.14.v20131031) is not blacklisted
Server: Jetty(8.1.14.v20131031)

{
 "a" : "b"
}
```

Please can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my serlvet was bound to

```
http://192.122.122.1:4040/data/json/
```

I was calling

```
http://192.122.122.1:4040/data/json (without the last slash) .
```

This resulting in a redirect -302 - which angular was not happy with.

Comment: Why was angularjs not happy with a 302?  I've run into a situation where my routing in Pyramid is expecting the slashes where AngularJS is not sending them, so I'm doing an HTTP Redirect resulting in the 302.  Is this a security thing?  Angular won't handle the OPTION query if it returns a 302?